# Write variables of different types on the same line with a specific FMT

Tags: fortran, format

I would like to write a series of characters preceeding a series of integers with a specific format *on the same line*. Like the following: `C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6`, for instance.

I succeeded to use the `ADJUSTL(FMT)` option for one type of variable so far:

```
WRITE(FMT,*) j
WRITE(*,"( "// ADJUSTL(FMT) //" a3)") (Letters(i),i=1,j)
```

Where `Letters` is a character array and `i,j` are integers. It displays correctly `C C C C C C`.

I've tried few different combinations in order to add the integers next to the characters but didn't find the right solution yet. I'm using gfortran to compile my F90 code.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand what you want, is there anything wrong with a `999(a1, i0, 1x)` format?

Comment: Because I'd like them on the same line. If I use ```WRITE(*,"(a1, i0,1x)"(Letters(i),i,i=1,6)```, I'll obtain 6 different lines for instance. Well, at least this is what I see using that option, maybe I'm not using it correctly

Comment: Ian Bush (reasonably) suggested `999(...)`, not simply `(...)`. These are two very different things.

Comment: I guess this is where my knowledge is limited, I thought 999 meant "whatever  before ```(...)```". I'm digging toward this and If you don't mind, I will get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, I've learned something new and even if I don't obtain 100% what I wanted, it does the trick :)

Comment: Rather than 999, or some other large number, use *. For example, `*(a1, i0, 1x)` . This is "infinite repeat count", where it repeats the format group as many times as is necessary to exhaust the I/O list.